# cakephp-2.x upgrade not working on php 7.2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

i have projects which are developed in CAKEPHP 2.X.these all projects are working on my server when my sever had php5.6 but when my server is update php5.6 to php7.2 all projects are stop working

Comment: and question is? error / log message is?

Comment: Error: Fatal Error (64): Cannot use 'object' as class name as it is reserved in [/var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Core/Object.php, line 18]

Comment: can you please delete `/var/www/html/vendor/` directory and perform `composer install` to re-install dependencies.

Comment: What version of CakePHP, exactly? Only later 2.x versions have support for PHP 7.2.

Comment: What version of CakePHP, exactly?

Answer : CakePHP 2.8

Answer (score 3):

The Object class has been deprecated and renamed to CakeObject

you must use at least cake 2.9 to solving the

```
 Cannot use 'object' as class name as it is reserved in ...
```

Comment: can i convert my 2.8 cakephp to 3.x ?

Comment: yes , but you need convert all your code to 3.x style https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html